# Returing timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: android, date, time, timestamp, milliseconds

I am having a problem with converting the date and time to milliseconds. There are no errors in the code but it's returning the wrong date and time in milliseconds.

This is the date that I'm converting: `2011-03-01 17:55:15` and it gives me this number: `-679019461843345152`.

This is the code I'm using:

```java
public long getDate(String s)
{
    //this is returning a timestamp but the wrong ones!!!
    String[] formats = new String[]{
            // "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            // "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
            //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
    };

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
    String st;

    for (String format : formats)
    {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
        //System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        st = new String(sdf.format(new Date(0)));
        System.err.format(format, st);
    }

    // compute nanoseconds from y, m...

    //return that number 
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(sdf.YEAR_FIELD, sdf.MONTH_FIELD, sdf.DATE_FIELD, sdf.HOUR0_FIELD, sdf.MINUTE_FIELD, sdf.SECOND_FIELD);
    return c.getTimeInMillis() * 1000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line c.set does not make any sense:

```
c.set(sdf.YEAR_FIELD, sdf.MONTH_FIELD, sdf.DATE_FIELD, sdf.HOUR0_FIELD, sdf.MINUTE_FIELD, sdf.SECOND_FIELD);
```

This should give you an idea:

```
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       try {
           dt = sdf.parse("2011-03-01 17:55:15"); 
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           System.err.println("There's an error in the Date!");
           return null;
       }   
       Date dt = sdf.parse("2011-03-01 17:55:15");   
       c.setTime(dt);
       System.out.println( c.getTimeInMillis() * 1000000);   
       System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

outputs:

```
1299002115000000000
Tue Mar 01 12:55:15 EST 2011
```

BTW, you are never accessing the parameter s.

Comment: thanks a lot but im having a small problem with it when i added the what u sent to my code it showed me an error it was saying Unhandled exception type ParseException for this Date dt = sdf.parse(s)

Comment: Usually every function that parses text will need to be inside a try-catch block, to handle unexpected strings. I'll update the answer to show you an example.

Comment: ok i got the same result you got and thanks a lot for your help but i have 1 last question the time you are entering is 17:55:15 and the result you are getting which is the same one i got is 12:55:15....????

Comment: UTC. vs EST :) . Play with that.